# Why it dosent post on my status wall?

Tags: c#, facebook

This is the code and its working no errors exceptions nothing.

```
AccessToken = "my at";
fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "hello";
dynamic result = fb.Post("178646422340235", parameters);
```

This is 178646422340235 the app id. I also use this app id in the App.config file in my project and also in App.config i have application secret id.

But i dont see on my facebook any new post/s

Whats wrong ? Should i use fb.Post ?

Comment: Does the post not appear in your activity log? did you get a post ID back in the response to the API call? if not, what did you get back?

Comment: I see now that my app i called it Games is now in my facebook on the left menu under: DEVELOPER. When i click on it i see: App ID/API Key
178646422340235
App Secret
Show
Sandbox Mode
On
Developer Alerts
See All
Developer Alerts
You do not have any developer alerts.
Insights
See All
Insights
Users Sharing
0 Daily New Users
0 Daily Active Users
0 Daily Content Shared
0.00 Feedback per Share

Comment: And what i wanted to do is to show on my wall just a simple post: "hello" but i dont have anything in my activity log and i see this Games app under DEVELOPER on my facebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.picture = "your pic URL [optional]";
messagePost.link = "your post URL [optional]";
messagePost.name = "your post name";

messagePost.caption = " Facebook caption";
messagePost.description = "Facebook description...";
messagePost.message = "[message] Facebook message...";

FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(acccessToken);
var postId = fb.Post("me/feed", messagePost);
```